# This program is blocked by group policy in Asp.net core 2.0 using Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wkhtmltopdf

My project is in Asp.net core 2.0 and hosted in godaddy windows shared server. I am trying to generate the pdf file in wwwroot/images. In local host file is creating and downloading but after uploading on server i am getting this error

" **This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator',
'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): This program is blocked by group policy.
For more information, contact your system administrator

at Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore.WkhtmlDriver.Convert(String wkhtmlPath, String switches, String html)**"

I have check the folder permission all are given to full control but still getting this error.
I am sharing my codes.Kindly help me on same.

web config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
 For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
   <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="aspNetCore" />
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
    resourceType="Unspecified"  />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
   stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES" value="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup" />
            <environmentVariable name="WEBCONNECTION_DETAILEDERRORS" value="1" />
            <environmentVariable name="WEBCONNECTION_USELIVERELOAD" value="False" />
            <environmentVariable name="WEBCONNECTION_OPENBROWSER" value="False" />
            <environmentVariable name="WEBCONNECTION_SHOWURLS" value="False" />
            <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
   </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Create file code

```
    [Route("CreateFile")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> CreateFile(OnlineFormModel model)
    {
        string filePaths = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), $" 
       {webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}/images", "OnlineForm.pdf");
        try
        {


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.HtmlData))
            {
                
                try
                {
                   
                    byte[] pdfData = GenerateFormPdf(model);
                    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(pdfData);

                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePaths, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }
                    Global.downloadFilePath = "images/OnlineForm.pdf";                     
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Global.SaveError(ex);
                    TempData["Message"] = ex.ToString();

                }
                            
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Global.SaveError(ex);
            TempData["Message"] = ex.ToString();

        }

        return Json(new Item {  Name = filePaths });
    }
```

---Generate pdf method

```
  public byte[] GenerateFormPdf(OnlineFormModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var data= _generatepdf.GetPDF(model.HtmlData);
            
            return data;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Global.SaveError(ex);
            TempData["Message"] = ex.ToString();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Above error is getting on
**var data= _generatepdf.GetPDF(model.HtmlData);**

Getpdf is pre defined function of Wkhtmltopdf

csproj code

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModule</AspNetCoreModuleName>
    <!--<AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModuleV2</AspNetCoreModuleName>-->
     
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>

</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="Controllers\DMAController.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Content Remove="Views\Home\Index1.cshtml" />
  <Content Remove="Views\Home\Index2.cshtml" />
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\style1.css" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ClosedXML" Version="0.95.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core" Version="1.7.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS" Version="2.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="Select.HtmlToPdf.NetCore" Version="21.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <!--<Content Include=""></Content>-->
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />-->

</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\banner1.svg" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\banner2.svg" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\banner3.svg" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\banner4.svg" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\js\site.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\js\site.min.js" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="logs\" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="Rotativa\Windows\wkhtmltopdf.exe">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore is actually running an executable application and apparently, it is not something allowed in the godaddy windows server.

This is why in the Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore [github page](https://github.com/fpanaccia/Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore) mentioned you need these files to run the examples.

> The structure will need to be on the folder of your project

```
.
├── Example
|   ├── Example.csproj
|   └── Rotativa
|   |   ├── Linux
|   |   |   └── wkhtmltopdf
|   |   ├── Mac
|   |   |   └── wkhtmltopdf
|   |   └── Windows
|   |       └── wkhtmltopdf.exe
└── Example.sln
```

> Those files will need to be included in your project with the
> propierty "Copy Always"

Comment: I am having same structure also i have added my csproj code file in question

Comment: @PrashantSharma Godaddy does not allow you to run an exe file. That is what Wkhtmltopdf is trying to do and that is why you get the error! Either change your pdf library or use another service to publish the website that allows it to run another executable file.